# Is there a way reverse associativity of function application in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

So I'm looking for a way to force some operators which are defined as right-associative to be applied in left associative manner. I've seen that Haskell has `$` operator, which changes precedence but sadly not the associativity of the function application.

To be exact, I specifically look for the way to make a long concatenation chain to evaluate arguments in left associative manner.

Does Haskell has something like this?

Comment: You could define your own application operator and give it the fixity you want. You can also name it `$`, if you want, but in that case you need to `import Prelude hiding (($))`.

Comment: Haskell has [`(Data.Function.&)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-) = `flip ($)`.

Comment: `"Hello World" & words & map length & sum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `$` *does* change the associativity of function application.

Normal function application associates to the left (and this behavior cannot be changed), so the expression `f x y` associates as:

```
f x y = (f x) y
```

On the other hand, `$` associates to the right (and this behavior is part of the library definition of `$` and could be changed by redefining your own version of `$` or some other operator), so:

```
f $ x $ y = f $ (x $ y) = f (x y)
```

with the first equality following from the associativity of `$` and the last equality following from its definition.

It's possible that what you're *really* talking about is not the associativity but rather the order in which the argument and function are combined.  Normal function application is `func arg`, but if you want `arg func`, you can do it with an operator.  The `(&)` operator in `Data.Function` does this.  It's a reversed version of `$`, which means that it associates to the left:

```
y & f & g = (y & f) & g
```

but it *ALSO* has a different definition, so `y & f` applies the function `f` to the argument `y`, instead of applying `y` to `f`.

So, you can, as in @Iceland_jack's example, write:

```
"Hello world" &    -- start with a string
   words &         -- break it into words
   map length &    -- get the length of each word
   sum             -- sum the lengths
```

If this is what you mean by "a long concatenation chain to evaluate arguments in left associative manner", then you've got your answer.  Note that the definition of `&` isn't too complicated.  It looks like this.  The `infixl` statement sets both the precedence and the (left) associativity of the operator:

```
infixl 1 &
(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
x & f = f x
```

If you are instead talking about an operator that applies a single function to *multiple* arguments but is written with the arguments first (in reverse order), like:

```
"string" ?? 2 ?? take   =   take 2 "string"
```

for some operator `??`, then I don't think there's any built-in operator like that, but you can do it yourself by defining an operator that is right associative like `$` but has the same core definition as `&`:

```
infixr 0 ??
(??) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
x ?? f = f x
```

Comment: What I assumed this question was asking for was something I often wanted when learning Haskell, a standard left-associative equivalent of `($)`. For the sake of completeness, that could be defined as `(#) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b; f # x = f x; infixl 0 #`—allowing, for example, `max # 2 + 3 # 2 * 3` instead of `max (2 + 3) (2 * 3)`.